$f(x-2f(y)) = 5f(x)-4x - 2f(y)$
Find all function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$f(x-2f(y))=5f(x)-4x-2f(y),\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$
Here is what I tried:
Have:
$$f(x-2f(y))-5f(x) = -4x - 2f(y)$$
Choose a value in $\mathbb{R}$ for $y=y_0 \in\mathbb{R}$ then:
$$f(x-2f(y_0))-5f(x)=-4x-2f(y_0)$$
Because the RHS is the linear function by $x$, it is surjective
Thus the LHS must be too
Then $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}: \exists u,v \in \mathbb{R}: t =f(u) - 5f(v) \Rightarrow f(t) = f(f(u)-5f(v))$
Let $x \rightarrow x-3f(y)$:
$$f(x-5f(y))=5f(x-3f(y))-4(x-3f(y))-2f(y)$$
Let $x \rightarrow x-f(y)$:
$$f(x-3f(y))=5f(x-f(y)) -4(x-f(y)) - 2f(y)$$
Thus the problem turn into find $f(x-f(y))$ and $f(f(x))$
Can anyone help me continue this part, thank you alots.

Proving with $f(x)=cx$ we get $c=1$ as a particular solution. Is it the only one?

Let $a=f(0)$ and $P(x,y)$: $f(x-2f(y))=5f(x)-4x-2f(y)$
$P(0,0)$: $$f(-2a)=3a ......(1)$$
$P(a,0)$: $$f(-a)=5f(a)-6a .......(2)$$
$P(2a,0)$: $$a=5f(2a)-4(2a)-2a$$
$$5f(2a)=11a......(3)$$
$P(4a,0)$: $$f(4a-2a)=5f(4a)-4(4a)-2a$$
$$5f(4a)=f(2a)+18a......(4)$$
$P(4a,-2a)$: $$f(4a-2f(-2a))=5f(4a)-4(4a)-2f(-2a)$$
By (1),$$f(4a-2(3a))=5f(4a)-4(4a)-2(3a)$$
$$f(-2a)=5f(4a)-22a$$
By (1) and (4):
$$3a=f(2a)+18a-22a$$
$$7a=f(2a)$$
$$35a=5f(2a)$$
By (3): $$35a=11a$$
$$a=0$$
$P(x,0)$: $$f(x-2a)=5f(x)-4x-2a$$
$$f(x)=5f(x)-4x$$
$$f(x)=x$$

Can you make a solution use my method? Thank you>

I'm not familiar with solving functional equations in general, could you give me any sources on or the main idea of your methods or toolbox so I can learn it and see what I can do?

you can see here P4: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2471843p20692315
